# Connecting with mysql server running on Compute Engine instance from GAE

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

How to communicate with the mysql server running on Compute Engine instance from google app engine? We are using google app engine as frontend. We want to host our database on the mysql server running on Compute Engine. Is there any way to achieve this?

We have gone through this:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mysql-remote-access

Code snippet:

```
if (os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE') and
  os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE').startswith('Google App Engine/')):
  db=MySQLdb.connect(host="InternalIP", port=3306, db='test_database', user='root',passwd="db_password")
else:
  db = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, db='test_database', user='root', charset='utf8')

cursor = db.cursor()
logging.info("Hey there looks like I am connected")
```

Comment: Compute Engine VM have IP address, so you can use TCP/IP (plus don't forget TLS for security) for communication

Comment: What is the problem you have encountered?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov When we try to connect with External Ip we are getting error : OperationalError: (2004, "Can't create TCP/IP socket (-1)")

Comment: @MeLight When we try to connect with External Ip we are getting error : OperationalError: (2004, "Can't create TCP/IP socket (-1)") Also tried with replacing external ip with internal ip. But got Same error.

Comment: I guess you're trying to connect from plain App Engine? it doesn't allow sockets. You have to use Managed VM to use sockets

Comment: @IgorArtamonov  Yes Exactly. How do we use VM for the same ? Any tutorials or link will help

Comment: There is an example guestbook app in the docs:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/#Python_Connect_to_your_database

Comment: @BrianMichelich topicstarter uses custom mysql server, deployed on own machine. it's not CloudSQL

Comment: @Kartik see https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11971

Comment: is this a paid app or in the free tier? Apps need to be pad for you to use sockets

Comment: @pbhowmick yes exactly. Got to know from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/Pp5zSkr_N48 Though we have a paid app. its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Igor's [comment above hints at](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11971#c3) how to get this working; I've managed to produce a working app, with the following changes to the [documented solution](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/#Python_Update_your_configuration_file).

1. Specify a public (external) IP address for the `host` parameter, rather than `unix_socket`.
2. Replace MySQLdb with [`pymysql`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/). In particular, you want to copy the `pymysql` directory from that GitHub repo into your application directory. Using `pymysql` also means that you don't need to add `MySQLdb` to the `libraries:` section of your app.yaml.
3. In `connections.py`, around line 52, change the following line:

   ```
   if _py_version == (2, 7) and not IRONPYTHON
   ```

   to

   ```
   if _py_version == (2, 7) and not IRONPYTHON and not os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'):
   ```
4. You may need to change your MySQL permission grants in mysql to allow access from [the App Engine source IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip).

The reason this workaround is needed is that the App Engine sockets library does not implement some of the async IO primitives used by the `_socketio` wrapper in `pymysql`. At the same time, the `MySQLdb` module shipped with App Engine wraps a C library which does not know how to use the App Engine `sockets` library (and probably does not have socket support compiled in).

I'll see if the latter combination can be addressed, but in the meantime, the above 3 steps should provide a workaround which can be used to connect to either your own MySQL or the [version 2 of Cloud SQL](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2015/12/the-next-generation-of-managed-MySQL-offerings-on-Cloud-SQL.html).

Comment: We are getting following error:
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.240.0.2' ([Errno 13] Permission denied)”). It is allowing to connect in shell with same username and password.

Comment: Error solved. We were using wrong ip range. Needed to grant permissions to remote sources. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: External IP should be used for making the connection.

Comment: You'll need to use the external IP address and allow the connection on the mysql side. Updated my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this code inside the Appengine then its not possible since appengine does not allow custom Socket connection. You need to use the Managed VM for this instance

Luckily, migrating from Appengine to Managed VM instance is quite simple. 
On the app.yaml, you just need to add **vm:true**

```
module: default

runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes 
vm: true
default_expiration: 1h

handlers:

# Main script
- url: .*
  script: main.main_app
  login: required
```

Deploy it by using this command (from the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/)):

```
gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml
```

Comment: App engine can connect to to cloud sql: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/ and sockets are available for paid apps:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/

Comment: Theres a very huuuuge differences between Cloud SQL and MySQL instance when talking about Google Cloud platform. CloudSQL is a service provided by GCP that can be used using their own client library or via REST api. MySQL intance needs a server and an open port to be consumed. Now about Sockets... Please read on the "limitations and restrictions" of using sockets on appengine on the same link you provided.

Comment: "You cannot bind to specific IP addresses or ports." Let me know how you can connect to a remote MySQL server without binding to these on appengine so that I can take a note.

Comment: @SugarRayTenorio In Managed VMs how do we connect to mysql on compute engine ?